# Suggestion for multi-project webpack config

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have 3 separated projects:

- base
- util
- main

What I want to achieve is that webpack should bundle the 3 projects into one index.html file with main.js, util.js, base.js, main.css, .... etc.

Every project can contain his own node_modules folder and the main project should be dependent on base and util.

How would I setup this environment?

Should I use the multi-compiler-mode? But then how can I create one index.html out of it?

Comment: What is the reason to have multiple node_modiles? The only one reason is when you use same modules with different versions which is not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is module bundler; it integrate modules into a single bundle. You need to:

- configure your projects as libraries
- configure exports of your libraries
- add libraries to package.json of your app
- use each library in your application

And webpack will join your projects into a common bundle which you have included in your html.

If you have all projects as subfolders of your application you just need to import them into app and use.